# error while creating superuser in django rest

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have made a model but I do not want username field as required_field, I want it as an optional field.

the model is below.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null= True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

but when I create a superuser then i get an error-

the error is -

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

how should I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default UserManager [comes with a `create_superuser()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L154) function that need a username to work.

You have overload the User model to identify accounts based on the email field (making username optional), but you need to overload the user manager too to make your own `create_user()` and `create_superuser()` methods that will work in that context. [This tutorial](https://krakensystems.co/blog/2020/custom-users-using-django-rest-framework) explain how to do it.